# Cannot parse the space between date and time in LocalDateTime

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I can't seem to parse my Localdatetime variable. It basically cannot follow my pattern. I want it to work with a space, not with a T.

My code will only work if the end_date is like this: "1997-21-21T12:12:21"
And not like this: "1997-21-21 12:12:21"

As you can see I have provided a picture of my error.
Here is my code:

```
 @NotNull
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'Т'HH:mm:ss")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'Т'HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'Т'HH:mm:ss")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'Т'HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime endDate;
```

I have also tried:

```
 @NotNull
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime endDate;
```

[image]

Comment: Quote the space

Comment: Is there a way to not quote it?

Comment: In the annotation, like you do with `T`

Answer (score 0):

No need to use two separate DateTime formatter just use below one I hope it should work.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime date;
```